# What is the action for a reducer built with createAsyncThunk

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm not really good at posting an accurate title for my question because I'm still fairly new to Redux, but here's what I'm trying to do:

I'm trying to create a middleware using `createListenerMiddleware` that basically carries out some logic when a certain action fires. In the `actionCreator` argument of the middleware, I have to pass in some action as such:

```
myMiddleware.startListening({
  actionCreator: myAction,
  effect: ...doSomething...
  ...
```

Currently, I used `createSlice` to create some functions to handle some redux implementations, and I also used `createAsyncThunk` with it:

```
export const logout = createAsyncThunk(
    "auth/logout",
    async () => {
        const res = await serveraxios.post(
            "logout",
            undefined,
            {
                withCredentials: true
            }
        );
        console.log(res);
    }
);

export const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: "auth",
    initialState,
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder
            ...
            .addCase(logout.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                console.log(action);
                return initialState;
            })
    }
});

export const selectAuth = (state: RootState) => state.auth.auth;
```

I'm trying to figure out what are the actions created in this case. For instance, if we did something without `createAsyncThunk` those actions (`setUser` & `removeUser`) can easily be extracted as such:

```
export const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: "user",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setUser: (state, action: PayloadAction<UserInterface>) => {
            state.user = action.payload
        },
        removeUser: (state) => {
            return initialState;
        },
    },

});

//Action creators generated for each case reducer function
export const { setUser, removeUser } = userSlice.actions;
```

In the case of `authSlice`, the actions are `CaseReducerActions`, how can I get the actions from `authSlice`?

Comment: Can you discover the properties with `console.log(authSlice.actions)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear: there are *action objects* ( `{type: "todos/todoAdded", payload: "Buy milk"}` ), *action creator functions* (`todoAdded("Buy milk"`), and *reducer functions* (`todoAdded(state, action) { state.todos.push(action.payload) }`).

Both `createSlice` and `createAsyncThunk` will generate new action type strings and action creator functions for you.  `createSlice` generates action creators based on the reducer functions you wrote in the `createSlice.reducers` object.  `createAsyncThunk` will automatically generate action creators for the `pending`, `fulfilled`, and `rejected` actions.

When you use `createSlice.reducers`, the individual "case reducer" functions such as `todoAdded` are later available as `todosSlice.caseReducers.todoAdded`.  However, any reducer functions you pass into the `builder` callback are *not* exposed that way.  `extraReducers` also does *not* generate any new action creator functions - it's only meant to listen to *existing* action types.

Comment: Understood. So in the case of `authSlice`, since I only passed my reducers in `builder` callback, they wont be available when I call `authSlice.actions`?

Comment: Yeah. `extraReducers` will _never_ generate new action creators.